# Counting Occurrences of integers in map c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to see if there are any duplicates of integers as I am inserting them using map because it`s auto sorting them when the numbers are inserted.

For example when I insert integers in the following order : 2 3 2 4 5 
I want an output like : at least a number is duplicated , ` I have tried many things but no success, any ideas?

The problems I am facing is this: You have a array of type integers and you have to find if there are any duplicates using map .

Comment: Please, try to explain your problem in a better way (and with a better formatting) and you will surely obtain some pretty answer.

Comment: As per docs for std::map, you can use `find` to check if something is in the map or not. You should probably read the docs for std::map at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map. You can also use `count` to determine the number of times something appears.

Comment: Very heplfull thank you , this site is awesome :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map::find`

```
int keyToInsert = 2;

std::map<int, int>::iterator it;
it = yourMap.find(key);
if(it != yourMap.end()){
    //alert user key exists
}
else {
    //key doesn't exist
}
```

See docs: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

Comment: That's looking for extant keys. My understanding is that they want to find if any of the mapped values are duplicates, not whether a key exists.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are approaching the problem seems fundamentally wrong. std::map is a data structure used to "map" logical entities in a container.

for example it can be used to map names to phone numbers. like this:

{ ("Tom", 2344556), ("Amanda", 545654), ...}

that would be an example of `std::map<std::string,int>` .

a map is NOT used for keeping seperate int values together. if you want that functionality you should look into other containers.

If you want to use a container that keeps values in order (and keeps duplicates) you can use std::list or std::vector, if you want a data structure where order is not guaranteed but access is fast and duplicates are generally avoided, you can use std::set

Comment: I would have used that but there is a problem , i need my container to be auto sorted when the numbers are inserted , can i use multiset for this?

Comment: look into #include <algorithm> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like (untested code):

```
bool check_for_duplicate(const std::map<my_key_type, int>& my_map)
{
  std::set<int> my_set;
  for (auto& i : my_map)
  {
    if (!my_set.insert(i.second).second)  // If it failed to insert
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to take "integers" as key and "number of repetition " as value of map .By doing so , you will not only able to figure out whether it a number was repeated but you would also figure out "how many times was it actually repeated " .I am sharing below code snippet .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,1,2,2,1,4,5};
  std::map<int,int> dup_map;
  for(int  i=0;i<=9;i++)
  {
        if(dup_map.find(arr[i])!=dup_map.end())
        {
            //key exist and hence update the dulpicate count;
            dup_map[arr[i]]++;
        }
        else{
        //it doesn't exist in map
        dup_map.insert(std::pair<int,int>(arr[i],1));//single count of current number

        }

  }
  for(std::map<int,int>::iterator it =dup_map.begin();it!=dup_map.end();it++)
  {

      cout<<"\n Number "<<it->first<<" is repeated "<<it->second<<" times ";
  }
}
```

Output of the program is as below :

```
Number 1 is repeated 3 times 
 Number 2 is repeated 3 times 
 Number 3 is repeated 1 times 
 Number 4 is repeated 2 times 
 Number 5 is repeated 1 times
```